# Semantic Issue - assignment to readonly property

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have been using this code to set the font of a `UILabel`and it has been working up until I installed Xcode 6.1:

```
self.navLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-85, 3, 320, 37)];
self.navLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
```

However when I now try to **archive** my application in Xcode 6.1, it fails with error on the line setting the label's font stating:

> Semantic Issue - assignment to readonly property

For some reason this error does **not** appear when **running** the application on my device. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just hit this. This happens on our build machine, which has Xcode 6.1, but not my development machine, which has Xcode 6.1.1. You might try updating to Xcode 6.1.1 and/or clearing `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`.

Workaround: use `-performSelector:withObject:`, like so:

```
 [self.navLabel performSelector:@selector(setFont:) withObject:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17]]
```